# Goldman Sachs Alumni in Trump Administration

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump, political-appointments

I've read in the press that Donald Trump has a lot of Goldman Sachs' Alumni in his administration.  I know that Steve Bannon worked for Goldman Sachs, but who else in Donald Trump's administration is a Goldman Sachs Alumnus?

Comment: Given that Tyler Durden at Zerohedge.com hates Goldman Sachs with a passion, calls them the Vampire Octopus, you, may want to check there for an answer.

Comment: A more interesting question is comparing Goldman alumni across different administrations. As well as other top level sell side institutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wall Street on Parade](http://wallstreetonparade.com/2017/01/heres-how-goldman-sachs-became-the-overlord-of-the-trump-administration/):

- Steve Bannon
- Steve Mnuchin, Secretary of the Treasury
- Gary Cohn, Director of the National Economic Council
- Jay Clayton, Chairman of the Securities and Exchange Commission

Note that Mnuchin and Clayton will require Senate confirmation.  Not sure about Cohn.  Bannon does not and is already part of the administration.

Erin Walsh and Anthony Scaramucci are on the transition team but do not have administration positions at this time.

Comment: Add another one.  James Donovan a managing director at Goldman Sachs is to be nominated as Deputy Treasury Secretary.

Comment: This answer would be better if it noted how long a given person worked there, how much they were paid or compensated, and why they left GS.  It might also be relevant if any of the above *returned* to working for GS after their respective stints in the government.